# Cross validation of averaged binomial GLMs ("model.avg" from package MuMIn)

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am spatially predicting binomial probabilities (using proportional data; `cbind` in R) across a spatial domain. I use the functions `get.models` followed by `model.avg` in the R package `MuMIn` to get averaged coefficients of models with delta AIC less than 2. This returns an object of class `model list` showing the component models and averaged coefficients. I would now like to use the cross validation `cv.glm` function (or any similar methods) from the R package `boot` to obtain leave-one-out cross validation prediction accuracy of this averaged model. However, I get the following warning when doing `cv.glm(data, model.avg output)`:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function model.avg.default.
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide suggestions on how to obtain leave one out cross validation on averaged models from the `MuMIn` package. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `cv.glm` cannot handle any of the model averaging objects provided by either `MuMIN` or `bbmle`. I am looking for a similar answer, yet not for exactly the same question as yours. During my search, I found a blog post where a function is presented that allows cross-validation of MuMIN models. I thought it might be handy for you.

Check out the link here [Noam Ross` Blog](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/2/20/model-selection-drug.html)

in the bottom you should find the proposed `Cross` function. I only works with 2 models so you will have to adjust it.

Did you find another solution already? If so, please post it here.